# Why isn't the first song of the .txt list being read?

Tags: python, list, for-loop, while-loop, readlines

My .txt file first song is Knife Party - Internet Friends
and second song is Galantis - Louder, Harder, Better.
But my code only outputs the second song. Why is that?

```
##5.4 Jukebox
failinimi = input("Sisesta failinimi: ")
 
if failinimi == "jukebox.txt":
    failinimi = "ut/jukebox.txt"
elif failinimi == "80ndad.txt":
    failinimi = "ut/80ndad.txt"
elif failinimi == "eesti_muusika.txt":
    failinimi = "ut/eesti_muusika.txt"
else:
    failinimi = "ut/edm.txt"
 
album = open(failinimi, encoding = "UTF-8")

järg = 1

for lugu in album:
    album_sisu = album.readline()
    while album_sisu != "":
        järg += 1
        print("{}. {}".format(järg, album_sisu.strip()))
        album_sisu = album.readline()
album.close
```

```
>>> %Run ut.py
Sisesta failinimi: s
1. Galantis - Louder, Harder, Better
```

Comment: Can you post the contents of your text file?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are already iterating over the file line, by line, but then you also execute `album.readline()` which will throw away the previous line. No need for that:

```py
with open(failinimi, encoding = "UTF-8") as album:

    järg = 1

    for lugu in album:
        if lugu != "":
            järg += 1
            print("{}. {}".format(järg, lugu.strip()))
```

No need to close the file if you can use `with open(...`

Also you can simplify the processing of the filename:

```py
failinimi = input("Sisesta failinimi: ")
 
if failinimi in ["jukebox.txt", "80ndad.txt", "eesti_muusika.txt"]:
    failinimi = "ut/" + failinimi 
else:
    failinimi = "ut/edm.txt"
```